# How to COnfigure Redmine and GitLab on One Apache Server?

Tags: apache2, redmine, gitlab

Basically Currently I have three servers running, two for Redmine, and one for GItLab. Now in order to remove the overhead of starting all three server one by one I want to just run one server and all three application works. 
I tried couple of things..but nothing worked so far.

Comment: The big problem is the version of Ruby.  RedMine wants Ruby 1.8 and GitLab needs 2.0.  In theory RVN should be able to get there, but I have had no luck either.

Comment: I've got Redmine & Gitlab Omnibus both working on a Ubuntu 12.04 system. You end up having to do the Gitlab Omnibus install first, then remove Ruby/Gems 1.8 from the system and add just Ruby 1.9.1/1.9.3 and setup defaults with update-alternatives.  Gitlab wants Nginx & I disabled it to use Apache2 proxy. Permissions were a challenge but can be done. Passenger was the next hurdle as you cannot use the built-in version that requires Ruby 1.8. You have to do a gem install of it into your Redmine and configure the user/group in Passenger. You can getting it working but it isn't easy.